# If $G$ acts transitively on $X$, show for some $x \in X$, $|G_x| = |G| / |X|$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

Suppose that $|G|$ and $|X|$ are finite. Show that the following are equivalent.

(a) $G$ acts transitively on $X$.

(b) For some $x \in X$, $|G_x| = |G| / |X|$.

(c) For every $x \in X$, $|G_x| = |G| / |X|$.

(Here, $G_x$ is the isotropy subgroup for an $x$ in $X$)

Been working on this for a while.

I know that if a group $G$ acts transitively on group $X$, then for every $x,y$ in $X$, there exists an $a$ in $G$ such that $ax=y$.

I also recognize that $|G_x| = |G| / |X|$ looks a lot like Lagrange's Theorem (If $K$ is a subgroup of a finite group $G$, then the order of $K$ divides the order of $G$. In particular, $|G| = |K| [G:K]$, or in other words, $|G|/|K| = [G:K]$ or $|G|/[G:K] = |K|$).

(Here, $[G:K]$ is the index of $K$ and $G$ and defined by the number of distinct right cosets of $K$ in $G$)

What I have done so far:

- I know that $G_x \lt G$ by definition.
- Next, I think I need to show that $[G:G_x]=|X|$ somehow.
- Finally use Lagrange's Theorem to say that $|G_x|=|G|/|G:G_x|$ and since $[G:G_x]=|X|$, $|G_x|=|G|/|X|$ and thus proven.

What I need help on is how can I show that $[G:G_x]=|X|$?

Comment: Are you familiar with the orbit-stabilizer theorem?

Comment: No I am not, I dont think we have covered it in my class-- maybe this question is meant to lead up to it?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Thank you, I tried my best to organize my question lol

Comment: Show that $gx=hx$ if and only if $g$ and $h$ lie in the same left coset of $G_x$. Then use that to show the number of elements in $X$ is the same as the number of left cosets of $G_x$.

Comment: gx=y=hx for g,h in G and x,y in X, right? I dont see how that connects to the cosets of Gₓ?

Comment: There are precisely $|G_x|$ group elements bringing $x\in X$ to whatever (transitivity) $y\in X$. Therefore, $|X|=\frac{|G|}{|G_x|}$

Comment: Ok update: i found this youtube video that explained it very well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=De09CSdzaeo

Comment: $gx=hx$ if and only if $h^{-1}gx=x$ if and only if $h^{-1}g\in G_x$.